# Add autocomplete input control as part of knockout view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following markup where any skills that exists as part of my view model are displayed.  I have a button in my html that runs the self.create function in my view model to create a new item in the EmployeeSkillsArray IF the user decides to add a new skill.  The input control below works as expected when the autocomplete portion is removed, however, my goal is to allow a user to begin typing a skill and if that skill exists allow them to select it from autocomplete.  It is THIS autocomplete functionality that seems to be causing the issue within the EmployeeSkillsArray.  I am able to see autocomplete working when an input control is placed OUTSIDE the array in my markup.

Is there a way to accomplish this goal of having an input control inside the foreach loop to display an item if it is in the array, otherwise allow the user to use autocomplete?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: EmployeeSkillsArray">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: EmployeeSkillId, visible: false" />
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="skillName" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a skill..." data-bind="value: SkillName, id: SkillsId, autoComplete: { selected: $root.selectedOption, options: $root.options }" />  <!-- corrected based on answer provided by f_martinez -->
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "autoComplete: function (){return { selected:selectedOption,options:options} }"
Message: selectedOption is not defined

I DO have selectionOption defined as part of my view model....

```
$(function () {
  ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var settings = valueAccessor();
      var selectedOption = settings.selected;
      var options = settings.options;
      var updateElementValueWithLabel = function (event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(element).val(ui.item.label);

          if(typeof ui.item !== "undefined") {
            selectedOption(ui.item);                
          }
      };

      $(element).autocomplete({
        source: options,
        select: function (event, ui) {
          updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
          updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
          updateElementValueWithLabel(event, ui);
        }
      });
      }
    };

    function ActivityViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      var remoteData;

      $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllSkills", "EmployeeSkills")',
        data: { },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
        remoteData = ($.map(data, function (item) {
          return {
          id: item.SkillId,
          name: item.SkillName
        };
      }));
    }
  });

  self.skills = remoteData;
  self.selectedOption = ko.observable('');
  self.options = ($.map(self.skills, function (element) {
                    return {
                        label: element.name,
                        value: element.id,
                        object: element
                    };
                }));

                var EmployeeSkill = {
                    EmployeeSkillId: self.EmployeeSkillId,
                    EmployeeId: self.EmployeeId,
                    SkillsId: self.SkillsId,
                    SkillName: self.SkillName,
                    SkillLevelId: self.SkillLevelId,
                    ApplicationUsed: self.ApplicationUsed,
                    selectedOption: self.selectedOption,
                    options: self.options
                };

                self.EmployeeSkill = ko.observable();
                self.EmployeeSkillsArray = ko.observableArray();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeSkills", "EmployeeSkills")',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: ko.toJSON({ 'UserId' : employeeId, 'ActivityHistoryId' : activityHistoryId }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        self.EmployeeSkillsArray(data); // Put the response in ObservableArray
                    }
                });

                self.cloneRow = function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddSkill", "EmployeeSkills")',
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: {},
                        success: function (data) {
                            self.EmployeeSkillsArray.push(data);
                        }
                    }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        alert(err);
                    });
                }
            }

            var viewModel = new ActivityViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

Comment: Yes, you DO have it. But looks like you fill the `self.EmployeeSkillsArray` with plain deserialized JSON response. It's not tied to `self.selectedOption` observable at all. Check and paste JSON response to your post.

Comment: Probably the only fix you will need is to change `selected: selectedOption` to `selected: $root.selectedOption` in the `autocomplete` binding.

Comment: @f_martinez thx that did it!  I will update above.